# Flow Input Validation Not Firing

Tags: visual-workflow, validation

I am trying to implement what should be a fairly simple validation on two inputs in a flow. There is a picklist called `{!Input_Type}` which can have one of three values (`{!CRS}, {!Email}, {!NewCustomer}`). A secondary text field called {!Customer_Input} which depending on the selection in the picklist above may be required (only in the case of {!CRS} at the moment). I'm trying to write a validation that says

IF `{!Input_Type}` has the value of `{!CRS}` and the `{!Customer_Input}` field is blank, throw an error.

Ideally I'd like to run a regex to ensure if the value is {!CRS} it is a number but that's a nice to have. I've tried using the following formulas but no luck. It seems like the NOT condition doesn't work at all and having to make the statement resolve to false to fire without using NOT is pretty nuts. Even just using NOT with only the LEN or ISBLANK conditions to reverse them doesn't seem to work. Also I know generally speaking for a picklist you'd have to use ISPICKVAL but I'm I tried including that and the flow designer tossed an error saying it was text but expecting a picklist so I probably got the syntax for referencing the field wrong.

```
NOT(AND({!Input_Type} == 'CRS', LEN({!Customer_Input}) == 0))

NOT(AND({!Input_Type} == 'CRS', ISBLANK({!Customer_Input})))
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!